# XML: .xsd: Error: The markup in the document following the root element must be well-formed

Tags: xml, xsd, schema

I am referring to [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1EBWzbO8lgs&index=5&list=PLsyeobzWxl7oanwaonj3iV3rxfTdEA2gC) to understand schema.

I have done the same as explained there:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<schema xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
targetNamespace="http://www.telusko.com/AlienSchema"
xmlns:tns="http://www.telusko.com/AlienSchema" 
elementFormDefault="qualified"></schema>

<complexType name="alienstype">
<sequence>
    <element name="alien" type="tns:alientype"></element>
</sequence>
</complexType>

<complexType name="alientype">
<sequence>
    <element name="name" type="string"></element>
    <element name="salary" type="integer"></element>
</sequence>
<attribute name="aid" type="ID" use=required""></attribute>
</complexType>
```

But I am getting the error as:

> Description   Resource    Path    Location    Type
>   The markup in the document following the root element must be well-formed.    AlienSchema.xsd /XMLExamples    line 7  XML Schema Problem

Could someone please let me know, where I am doing wrong and why I am getting this error. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You need to write a complete question and provide in it all the info required in order for someone to understand. A video is not helpful

Answer (score 1):

You have two errors in your XML/XSD file:

- You're closing the `<schema ...>` tag right at the beginning causing the file to be **not well-formed**.
- Your attribute `<attribute name="aid" type="ID" use=required""></attribute>` does not properly define its value `use`. It should be `use="required"` instead.

So a correct file would look like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<schema xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:tns="http://www.telusko.com/AlienSchema" targetNamespace="http://www.telusko.com/AlienSchema" elementFormDefault="qualified">
    <complexType name="alienstype">
        <sequence>
            <element name="alien" type="tns:alientype"/>
        </sequence>
    </complexType>
    <complexType name="alientype">
        <sequence>
            <element name="name" type="string"/>
            <element name="salary" type="integer"/>
        </sequence>
        <attribute name="aid" type="ID" use="required"/>
    </complexType>
</schema>
```